# Shutdown with keyboard press doesn't work

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard-shortcuts, init, reboot

I have a Debian Jessie build, and I want to add keyboard shutdown. I've tried the following, without any success:

**Attempt 1**

To `/etc/inittab` I added

```
ca:12345:ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t1 -a -r now
```

I also tried

```
ca::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t1 -a -r now
```

Then I tried to create a file `/etc/init/control-alt-delete.conf` and added:

```
start on control-alt-delete    
exec /sbin/shutdown -h now "Control-Alt-Delete pressed"
```

**Attempt 2**

I also, installed `kbd` and to `rc.local` added:

```
loadkeys << EOF
alt keycode 103 = KeyboardSignal
EOF
```

And to `/etc/inittab` added:

```
kb::kbrequest:/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Again nothing.

**Attempt 3**
To `/etc/kbd/default.map.gz`, I added

```
keycode 111 = Select
        altgr   control keycode 111 = KeyboardSignal
        control alt     keycode 111 = KeyboardSignal
```

And to `/etc/inittab` I added

```
kb:12345:kbrequest:/sbin/shutdown -t1 -h now
```

I've had no success with any of these attempts. I obviously restarted after each attempt.

My ultimate goal is to allow reboot from the login prompt page when you use console without GUI

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sysvinit is deprecated in favor of systemd in Debian jessie.  So you cannot change the system's behavior by editing `/etc/inittab` or `/etc/init/*.conf`.

When user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> on the console, systemd invokes `/lib/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target` which is by default a symlink to `reboot.target` in the same directory, that results in a simple reboot.

You can override that behavior by creating `/etc/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target`.  If you want to shut down and power off the system, make a symlink to `poweroff.target`:

```
ln -f /lib/systemd/system/poweroff.target /etc/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target
```

See [systemd's manual](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html) about special targets mentioned above.

Comment: That's fantastic thank you. Is it possible to change the keyboard shortcut from Ctrl+Alt+Del to something else? Or is that keyboard shortcut hardwired?